# Finding the solution of $u_x + y u_y = 0$ using $u(0, y) = y^3$, Part 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I recently asked and bountied [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3777880/356308) question, which primarily focused on why *my* attempted solution didn't make sense. As I said in the comments to the answers, I don't think any of them properly address the main issue. Yuri Negometyanov's answer, although a useful aside, is clearly, given its complexity, not what the author had in mind at the introductory chapter of a PDE textbook. On the other hand, it seems to me that H. H. Rugh's answer, although itself unclear to me, likely identifies the issue: The textbook author has used notation poorly, and so the ideas that they are trying to convey are not clear. So I now wanted to focus on whether or not, and how, the *author's* solution makes sense.

The author's solution to this problem is as follows:

> Putting $x = 0$ in (7), we get $y^3 = f(e^{-0}y)$, so that $f(y) = y^3$. Therefore, $u(x, y) = (e^{-x} y)^3 = e^{-3x}y^3$.

If we put $x = 0$ in (7), we get $u(0, y) = f(e^{-0} y) = f(y)$.

In the problem statement, it was said that we have the auxiliary condition $u(0, y) = y^3$. So putting this all together, we have that $u(0, y) = f(y) = y^3$. But, clearly, this does *not* get us to the author's claim that $u(x, y) = (e^{-x} y)^3 = e^{-3x}y^3$. So it is a total mystery to me how the author is deducing these things.

I suspect that there are notational problems here, which is why there seems to be no path to the author's solution. And these notational problems are likely what led to the confusion in the other question.

So can anyone untangle what's going on here?

Comment: "clearly, this does not get us to the author's claim" - but it does. $u(x,y) = f(e^{-x}y)$ and $f(y)=y^3$. Therefore $f(e^{-x}y)=e^{-3x}y^3=u(x,y)$.

Comment: @tomasliam I don't see how $u(x,y) = f(e^{-x}y)$ and $f(y)=y^3$ implies $f(e^{-x} y)=e^{-3x}y^3=u(x,y)$. If this is true, then there is intermediate reasoning that you have not included.

Comment: Substitute $y\to e^{-x}y$.

Comment: @tomasliam And how exactly does such a substitution make sense? You're effectively saying that $y = e^{-x}y$. And this is precisely why I said that I suspect that there are notational problems here. And I edited the comment.

Comment: No I am not. We are saying that when $f$ takes in an input, it returns the cube. So input $e^{-x}y$. If it confuses you write $f(z)=z^3$ instead.

Comment: @tomasliam So what is the full calculation that you are proposing if $f(z) = z^3$? Write it out for me so that I can see precisely what you're claiming.

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote it out. $f$ is a function that inputs one variable. You know that it always returns the cube of the input. That is what $f(y)=y^3$ states. So you just want to input $e^{-x}y$. I just used $z$ so you could write $f(z)=z^3$ and have $z=e^{-x}y$ as I thought it might make things more straight forward. Just think about it, any value of the input (3, -264.33, ... anything) always yields the cube as the output. So whatever $y$ and $x$ are we have that $f(e^{-x}y)=e^{-3x}y^3$.

Comment: The notation is NOT poor. The argument by H. H. Rugh is clear, and is in fact very pedantic to get the point across. You have an entire mathematical community telling you the argument is valid. You should stop, reassess your point of view, and look deeply into what people are telling you.

Comment: You are missing something very, very elementary.....

Answer (score 1):

On the characteristic lines, $u$ is constant and we have the following relation between $x$ and $y$, which define the characteristics, see (http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Partial_differential_equation#General_Form_of_First-Order_Partial_Differential_Equation) and in particular the section on the `Characteristic system'.

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}
\end{equation}

Integrating both sides we get $x=\log(y)+C$ or $y\exp(-x)=C$

Since $u$ and $y\exp(-x)$ are both arbitrary constants you can
set one equal to an arbitrary function of the other, this function describes how $u$ changes as one moves between characteristic lines.

Giving $u(x,y)=f(y\exp(-x))$

\begin{equation}
u(0,y)=f(y)=y^3
\end{equation}

This then defines the function $f$, it cubes its argument, therefore

\begin{equation}
u(x,y)=\left(y\exp(-x)\right)^3
\end{equation}

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

$$u_x+yu_y=0 \tag 1$$
I suppose that you understand and agree with the general solution of the PDE :
$$u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x}) \tag 2$$
in which $f$ is an arbitrary function if no condition is specified.

This is easy to check using the chain rule for partial derivatives.

$u_x=-ye^{-x}f'$

$u_y=e^{-x}f'$

$u_x+yu_y=-ye^{-x}f'+y\:e^{-x}f'=0$

Thus Eq.$(2)$ satisfies $(1)$ and so is solution of the PDE what ever the function $f$ is.

The next step is to find what is the right function $f$ which satisties the condition $u(0,y)=y^3$ . Apparently you don't understand this step.

How the function $f$ is determined ?

For $x=0$ Eq.$(2)$ gives $u(0,y)=f(y)$.

In order to satisfy the condition this requires $f(y)=y^3$ .

So the function $f$ is known now. Doesn't matter the symbol of the variable in the function. One can write $f(t)=t^3$ or $f(v)=v^3$ or any other symbol for the variable. The function is the same. For example :
$$f(\chi)=\chi^3$$
Then to find the solution of the PDE which satisfies the confition one have to put the function $f(\chi)$ into the general solution $(2)$.

Note that in $(2)$ the variable is not $\chi=y$ but is $\chi= ye^{-x}$.

Thus $f(ye^{-x})=f(\chi)=\chi^3=(ye^{-x})^3=y^3e^{-3x}$

$$u(x,y)=f(ye^{-x})=y^3e^{-3x}$$